# What am I doing wrong with his php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

What my intention is to put a table on my website containg some fields from a datbase which contain an ID

```
$con = mysqli_connect('hostname','username','password','dbname');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}



$sql="SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE `Student UID` = '".$id."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
echo 
echo "<table><tr><th>Product</th><th>Cost</th></tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['MenuItemName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Price'] . "</td>";


    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

At the moment when I am running this, I am jut getting a table like this

```
+---------+-------+
| Product | Price |
+---------+-------+
```

My database looks like this

```
+--------------+-------+-------------+
| MenuItemName | Price | Student UID |
+--------------+-------+-------------+
| Foo          |    99 |       12345 |
| Foo2         |    11 |       11111 |
| Foo2         |    11 |       12345 |
+--------------+-------+-------------+
```

What am I doing wrong with this?

Comment: sidenote: `'Student UID'`

Comment: Sorry na mayor @RodrigoDuterte haha

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE 'Student UID' = '".$id."'";
```

to:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE `Student UID` = '".$id."'";
```

Shout solve your issue.

Comment: Im still not getting anything inside my table?

Comment: Any error output? I tested this exactly code (without that "echo" after $result line, of course), and it worked for me.